# Clickwrap not working on Modal (Chrome or Edge)

Tags: google-chrome, modal-dialog, microsoft-edge

I noticed an issue that I cannot resolve even after the basic troubleshooting (with Antivirus, Defender, etc..)

I use an Investment Portal and this portal asks me select a fund to invest my money.   I choose the fund and a Modal pops up.

I need to enter the amount of $$ I want to invest and they force me to Download the product disclosure so I am aware how the product works.  After the download the box "I accept the T&C" should be enabled and then I proceed clicking in the button "INVEST"

If I don't download the document the box cannot be ticked....and I cannot invest.

It was all working fine until a few months ago (cannot remember when) but now, even though I download the document the tick box will not be enabled.

1. The issue is happening in both Chrome and Edge
2. I have disabled my Antivirus....same behaviour.
3. Have disabled Defender on Windows 10....same behaviour.

However....I used the TOR Browser and it DOES WORK.

The problem is NOT with the Investment website as nobody else seems to be having the problem.  Also, I used another website (for job application) that uses the same style of Modal and again it will NOT WORK.

So, what could be the problem then ?

Thanks
Marcelo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjkRT.png)

Comment: Have you tried on other machine's Edge and Chrome to see if the issue still exists? Are there any steps which you can provide to let us reproduce the issue on a certain website? I think the issue is more related with the websites' compatibility and I suggest that you can provide the feedback about the issue to the websites.

Comment: Hi Yu Zhou Thanks for getting back.   Yes I have tried in another machine and it DOES WORK.   Therefore the problem is with my machine.   
But what could be wrong ?
I have already reported the issue to the websites but they say that this is the first time they ever heard of the problem.

Comment: The issue is so wired. I suggest that you can compare the browser versions and settings with the working one and not working one to see if there's any difference. Make sure that you're using the latest version of Edge and Chrome. You can also try to open the pages with incognito window and disable all the extensions to see if it can fix the issue.

Comment: Good point...thanks Yu.  I will give it a try.